# Does struct assignment guarantee padding to also be equal

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer

Say I have a struct with 2 fields and the implementation of C that I have also has some padding between these fields.

If I create two variables of the struct and assign one to another, will the padding be guaranteed to be equal?

I know that for most compilers it would be so (because they just call memcpy), but I want to know what is specified about the padding in the standard?

Intention for this question is, can I use `memcmp` to check equality of structs.

Say I have a compiler which emits code that just assigns all the members of the struct instead of doing `memcpy`, will it be a valid implementation of the assignment of struct operation?

Comment: You are concerned about the padding *values*, not the sizes, correct?

Comment: In general padding will not be the same content. It seems to be uninitialized. In the case of `x = y`, I think that whether padding is the same or not is implementation dependent.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes the values of the padding, The size of the padding will be same because they are the same struct.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so I cannot use `memcmp` to compare the equality of structs?

Comment: It is better to think that you can not use `memcmp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard says in a [note 51 of **6.2.6.1 General**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note51):

> Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.

Comment: Thanks, that addresses the problem directly. Infact note 52 also directly talks about memcmp. But that is over ==. The same idea.

Comment: Yeah, 52 is interesting too. Do you think it should be added?

Comment: Strictly speaking it is about == operator which is not available for structs. But you can add it as extra to probably throw some light on the motivation behind how it is designed.

Comment: Note there is a lot of legacy code around that uses `memcmp` to compare structures, `memcpy` to copy them and `bzero` to clear them - So even if the standard says "you don't need to", most compilers will implement "exact" copies of structures because they can simply not afford to break this code.

Answer (score 6):

> **6.2.6.1 General**
> ...
> 6    When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member
> object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take
> unspecified values.<sup>51)</sup> The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be
> a trap representation.
>
> 7    When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
> representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members
> take unspecified values.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>51) Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Footnote 51 directly addresses your question - contents of padding bits may not be copied over in assignment, so `memcmp` may not work for comparing two `structs` for equality.

Comment: Thanks, that addresses my problem.

Comment: Accepting @EugeneSh's answer because it was answered first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can use `memcmp`, because the memory between the members (i.e. the content in the "padding"-area) is not guaranteed to have a certain value, and assigning such a struct-object to another is not required to copy the padding content as well.

Comment: My hunch is with yours, but as this is a [language-lawyer] question you're expected to provide proof from the Standard :)

Comment: So basically you mean that calling memcmp on a struct with padding would be undefined behavior because you are attempting to read bytes which are uninitialized?

Comment: What if the struct on the RHS of the assignment is initialized by the means of memset?

Comment: @Quentin: right - got interrupted by my kids :-) Everything clear in the meanwhile...